# Printing some metrics from a Windows machine

Tags: ruby, beginner, windows

New to Ruby here. I just made a script that print some metrics from a Windows machine about its disk. The script works fine and as I wanted it to. Now, since I'm new to the ruby and programming world, I'd like to ask you if anyone could help me to make to code look better or if there's other more efficient way I could have wrote it.

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.0'
require 'sensu-plugin/metric/cli'
require 'socket'

class LogicalDiskMetric < Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::Graphite

  option :scheme,
    :description => "Metric naming scheme, text to prepend to .$parent.$child",
    :long => "--scheme SCHEME",
    :default => "#{Socket.gethostname}"

  #Run a wmic command to get some stats about the disks usage
  def get_logical_disk_metrics
    tmp = `wmic logicaldisk get caption, drivetype, freespace, size`.split("\n")
    logical_disk = []
    bytes_to_gbytes = 1073741824

    #Convert data from bytes to gigabytes and find the used space (size-free)
    tmp.each do |disk|
      disk = disk.split(" ")
      if disk[1].to_i == 3
        disk[2] = (disk[2].to_f/bytes_to_gbytes).round(2)
        disk[3] = (disk[3].to_f/bytes_to_gbytes).round(2)
        disk.push((disk[3].to_f - disk[2].to_f).round(2))
        logical_disk.push(disk)
      end
    end
    return logical_disk
  end

  #Add the disks usage in %
  def get_logical_disk_usage_percentage(logical_disk)
    logical_disk.each do |disk|
      disk.push(((disk[2].to_f/disk[3].to_f)*100).round(2))
      disk.push(100.00-disk[5])
    end
    return logical_disk
  end

  def run
    timestamp = Time.now.utc.to_i
    logical_disk = get_logical_disk_metrics()
    logical_disk = get_logical_disk_usage_percentage(logical_disk)

    logical_disk.each do |disk|
      metrics = {
        :"logical_disk_#{disk[0]}" => {
          :"size(Gb)" => disk[3],
          :"free_space(Gb)" => disk[2],
          :"free_space(%)" => disk[5],
          :"used_space(Gb)" =>  disk[4],
          :"used_space(%)" => disk[6] 
        }
      }
      metrics.each do |parent, children|
        children.each do |child, value|
          output [config[:scheme], parent, child].join("."), value, timestamp
        end
      end
    end
    ok
  end
end
```

Comment: Magic, but you can just delete line `return logical_disk`

Comment: Did no try it, but even if I can do it, are you sure it's a good thing to do? I mean, to me it only adds a bit of complexity to understand the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general pointers:

Refrain from using `tmp` as variable names. `raw_output` will do the job better.

Working with arrays as object replacement (`x[0]` is the caption, `x[1]` is the type...) is cumbersome, unreadable, and difficult to maintain. I suggest moving to Hash:

```
tmp.map(&:split).select { |_, drivetype, _, _| drivetype.to_i == 3 }.map do |caption, drivetype, freespace, size|
  {
    caption: caption,
    drivetype: drivetype,
    freespace: (freespace.to_f/bytes_to_gbytes).round(2),
    size: (size.to_f/bytes_to_gbytes).round(2),
    usedspace: ((size.to_f - freespace.to_f)/bytes_to_gbytes).round(2)
  }
end
```

This code returns an array of hashes, one for each disk with drivetype '3'. The variables (`caption`, `drivetype`, etc...) are created when ruby translates the array to the list of variables declared, so actually the `tmp.map(&:split).map { |caption, drivetype, freespace, size| ... }` is like saying:

```
tmp.map do |disk|
  disk = disk.split
  caption = data[0]
  drivetype = data[1]
  freespace = data[2]
  size = data[3]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Wow Uri, many thanks for that awesome answer! I look into it!